# Rewrite Rule: Create links with php and replace ID with Name

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Before I explode I want to ask you the following.

I have this:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?page=item&item_id=42
```

And what I want is this:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/item/name-of-the-item/
```

My solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1&item_id=$2 [L]
```

Brings me to this:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/item/42/
```

This works fine so far but how do I get the name instead of the pure id?
I have stored everything in a database means the id has an particular name.
For example ID=42 and Name=Test

This is how I build my hrefs:

```
<a href=" <? echo 'item/'.$controller->getItem($id)->getId(); ?> /">
```

They work and I became http://subdomain.example.com/item/test/ when I exchange `getId()` with `getName()` but the website is just blank with no content.

I would appreciate If any one of you can point me into the right direction of what am I missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your page:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?page=item&item_id=42
```

For:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?page=item&item_name=Test
```

(changes are needed in the PHP code of the page!)

And after that, you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&item_name=$2 [L]
```

If you always use `ID` with numbers, and `item_name`  with letters, you can even mix the two:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&item_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&item_name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too !

Comment: Croises, if you have some time would you please take a look on my new question. That would be totally awesome!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434040/mod-rewrite-form-url-with-multiple-parameters-to-a-shorter-one-without-middlep