# mod_rewrite: form URL with multiple parameters to a shorter one (without middleparts)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Right now I work with these type of URLs:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?page=contact
http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?page=about
http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?page=category&category_id=1
http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?page=item&item_id=1
```

And I want them to look like this:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/contact/
http://subdomain.example.com/about/
http://subdomain.example.com/category-1/
http://subdomain.example.com/item-1/
```

So, I accommodate my page/php file into the following:

```
category_id -> category_name
item_id     -> item_name
```

And my .htaccess file to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1&category_name=$2 [L]
```

Which gives me some nice URLs but I want them without the middlepart. In other words I want to get rid of "category" and "item" for example.

```
http://subdomain.example.com/category/category-1/ -> http://subdomain.example.com/category-1/
```

When I try and change my .htaccess to the following I get this to work. BUT you can see that I had to comment out the 2nd line and so my contact page doens't work any longer :(

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=category&category_name=$1 [L]
```

I know it has something to do with the parameters, one against two but I can't figure out which way I have to follow to get this to work which makes me to have fit.

I really would appreaciate if somebody can help me out solving this!

Comment: I would like to try, as you ask me personally. But I have trouble understanding what you are trying to change how. Can you add at the end a few examples: I have (before rewrite) -> I want

Comment: I don't understand when word `category` is used like that or as example. Same for `item` and `name`. Is it necessary or even possible to differentiate `category_name` and `item_name` in the htaccess ?

Comment: Sorry, they have rejected my edit :( -> I have `http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?page=category&category_id=1
http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?page=item&item_id=1` and I want this: `http://subdomain.example.com/fantasy-books-1/
http://subdomain.example.com/lord-of-the-rings-1/`

Comment: I think it's possible to differentiate but I don't know if it has to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand...

```
RewriteEngine on

# Not for real file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# for category-1/ and all like xxxxx-xxx-nnn
RewriteRule ^([^/]+-\d+)/?$ /index.php?page=category&category_name=$1 [L]

# for contact/ or about/ or other/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The result :

```
 http://subdomain.example.com/lord-of-the-rings-1/
   ->  http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?page=category&category_name=lord-of-the-rings-1
```

Comment: Unfortunately that was not what I was looking for. Right now I have implemented a different solution and also a different of building my links. So it's not beneficial to post my current htaccess file here as a solution. Anyway, thank you very much for your quick response Sir!

Comment: Thank you. And sorry for not having helped more than that.